# Sort sub array by total charges

Tags: php, mongodb, smarty

I want to perform sorting by total_charges.
My mongodb data is like following

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("534bceb303ea2ecd1de86944"),
    "Hotel" : [ 
        {
            "0" : 0,
            "hotelId" : "123",
            "name" : "HOTEL - DEMO1",
            "city" : "Paris",
            "address1" : "Demo -Paris ",
            "total_charges" : 1653.76,
            "propertyAvailable" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "0" : 0,
            "hotelId" : "134",
            "name" : "HOTEL - DEMO2",
            "city" : "Paris",
            "address1" : "Demo Paris ",
            "total_charges" : 1875.71,
            "propertyAvailable" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "0" : 0,
            "hotelId" : "145",
            "name" : "HOTEL - DEMO3",
            "city" : "Paris",    
            "address1" : "Demo Paris ",
            "total_charges" : 1143.18,
            "propertyAvailable" : 1
        }
    ],
    "size" : 3
}
```

I tried something like this in PHP. Find is working properly but sorting is not working

```
        $dcnew = $dbnew->selectCollection($a);
        $results = $dcnew->find()->sort(array("Hotel.total_charges" => 1));
        echo "<pre>";
        foreach($results as $test) {
               $test1=$test;
        }
        echo "</pre>";
    $smarty->assign("result",$test1['Hotel']);
    $smarty->assign('template',"mongo_hotel_search_listing.tpl");
```

Any idea why it is not working? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following answer is working for this question

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ "$unwind": "$Hotel" },{ $sort : { 'Hotel.total_charges' : 1 } },{$group:{_id:'$Hotel.name',Hotel:{$push:{'total_charges':'$Hotel.total_charges'}}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are actually sorting the "top" level documents and not the sub-documents in the array as you require.

So the basic query form ( not directly as PHP so more people get it) is actually done using aggregate where you cannot pre-sort on insertion or modification of elements in the array:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // De-normalize the array into individual documents
    { "$unwind": "$Hotel" },

    // Actually sort the array documents
    { "$sort": { "Hotel.total_charges": 1 } },

    // Put everything back into original form, now sorted
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "Hotel": { "$push": { 
            "hotelId" : "$Hotel.hotelId",
            "name" : "$Hotel.name",
            "city" : "$Hotel.city",
            "rateCurrencyCode" : "$Hotel.rateCurrencyCode",
            "address1" : "$Hotel.address1",
            "total_charges" : "$Hotel.total_charges"
        }}
    }}
])
```

Or otherwise reverse the sort order to `-1` to get highest to lowest.

And the result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("534bceb303ea2ecd1de86944"),
    "Hotel" : [
            {
                    "hotelId" : "1033132",
                    "name" : "VICTORIA PALACE HOTEL - DEMO: T2",
                    "city" : "Paris,FR",
                    "rateCurrencyCode" : "SAR",
                    "address1" : "Demo Paris ",
                    "total_charges" : 1143.18
            },
            {
                    "hotelId" : "11711",
                    "name" : "HOTEL DU TRIOMPHE - DEMO: T2",
                    "city" : "Paris,FR",
                    "rateCurrencyCode" : "SAR",
                    "address1" : "Demo -Paris ",
                    "total_charges" : 1653.76
            },
            {
                    "hotelId" : "17421",
                    "name" : "RAPHAEL HOTEL - DEMO: T2",
                    "city" : "Trocadero,Paris,FR",
                    "rateCurrencyCode" : "SAR",
                    "address1" : "Demo Paris ",
                    "total_charges" : 1875.71
            }
    ]
}
```

But very easy to translate to PHP code.

Comment: No, This one is not working. I executed this query in Robomongo where my database is stored. Any other solution?

Comment: @Mayuri Sorry there were a few typing mistakes that have been edited along with clearly showing the result.

Comment: This one is working but showing result only{
    "result" : [],
    "ok" : 1
} Is it required to take all the fields in $push. because my data is not this much. It contains lots of fields

Comment: @Mayuri This works with the data as shown in your question. And all the steps here are necessary in order to sort an array by one of its fields without updating the documents permanently. That is what your question is about. Adapting to actual data that you have not shown is up to you. But your question has been answered.

Comment: `@Neil Lunn`Thank you for answer. I am edited question with all fields which is present in collection.